# Postgres update tableA and tableB only if tableB.field is a certain value atomically

Tags: postgresql

I've got these two tables, and I want to make an update to one record from both of them together.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    credit numeric(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE jobs
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    state character varying(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
    cost decimal NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT jobs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I only want to make an update if a job is in a pending state however.

Here's some psuedo code to show the update I'm after:

```
select state, cost from jobs where id = 'some_job_id';

if (state == 'pending') {
    update jobs set state = 'success' where id = 'some_job_id';
    update users set credit = credit - cost where id = 'some_user_id';
}
```

This is easily done with separate queries, but I'm unsure how to make this whole thing concurrency safe, such that if this whole operation is run twice simultaneously for the same job id, there is no chance that both operations will read the job state as 'pending' before completing (I don't want to charge the user twice). How do I accomplish this? Is a transaction what I'm after here? Do I need to rework the schema?

**Update:**

I should have included this, but I actually do have the user id in the jobs table as well. I've tweaked this to use a transaction like so:

```sql
BEGIN;
UPDATE users SET credit = credit - jobs.cost
FROM jobs WHERE users.id = jobs.user_id
AND jobs.state = 'pending'
AND jobs.id = ?;

UPDATE jobs SET state = 'success' WHERE id = ?;
COMMIT;
```

This seems to work, but I still can't really find clear documentation that says this is concurrency safe. I always understood transactions simply as a way to roll back changes made by multiple queries if one inside the transaction fails. If this transaction starts twice simultaneously for the same job id, is there any risk that I would update `user.credit` twice?

Comment: You would typically wrap the 2 update statements in a single transaction, either in your stored proc/trigger, or at the application level.

Comment: You need to rework the schema. The problem being there in no explicit relationship between Users and Jobs. There is only the implied relationship, from the queries, that the ID must be same in both tables. Since the id is unique in each table it means a user can only be associated to 1 job and every job requires a different user.  That does not seem to be a very stable/effective model. Just a guess but perhaps add the user id to the jobs table and create a FK.

Comment: @Belayer I should have included that but I do have the user_id in the jobs table. Would my updated example work as intended? Would it be fully safe to run concurrent queries with this method?

Comment: As Tim already wrote, wrapping inside a transaction will do what you require. However your revised code is clearly wrong. You are settling the job state to pending instead of success. This will clearly cause you to re-charge the customer every time the procedure is called.

Comment: Just as an aside. If relying on the transaction on concurrency grounds worries you, you can always be doubly certain by simply changing the order of your updates. Update the job table, before you update the user table.

Comment: Oh derp meant to set that to 'success'. Thanks for pointing that out.